# How to Massive Delete in PHP Activerecord with comparison operators

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

From this link
http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Basic_CRUD
I got the following:

```
6 # MASSIVE DELETE
7 # Model::table()->delete(WhereToDelete);
8 Post::table()->delete(array('id' => array(5, 9, 26, 30));
9 # DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE id IN (5, 9, 26, 30)
```

However, I need to delete from a table WHERE DATE is less than 2012-01-01 00:00:00 
AND where CATEGORY equal to JOURNAL

The following code does NOT work:

```
Model::table()->delete(array('date'=>'<2012-01-01 00:00:00','category'=>'journal'));
```

If I leave:

```
Model::table()->delete(array('category'=>'journal'));
```

it deletes only the WHERE category equals to journal.
So my question is HOW can I implement COMPARISON operator into that query with the date?

I've searched everywhere online and can't find the answer anywhere.
Would really appreciate your input!
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#methoddelete_all

```
YourModel::delete_all(array('conditions' => array('date >= ? AND category <= ?', $thedate,$cateogry)));
```

Answer (score 0):

delete_all did not work in my case. You can find another way [here](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Basic_CRUD)

```
# MASSIVE DELETE
# Model::table()->delete(WhereToDelete);
Post::table()->delete(array('id' => array(5, 9, 26, 30));
```